# Change Cell Style According to its Value?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm creating an application that is based on a form and `DataGridView` control.

I'm binding information from a database and what I'm trying to do now is to change the font style and color of the column propeties according to its value which can be `"Urgent","Haute","Normale"` .

Here is the code I'm using but it didn't worked, may some one tell me what is going wrong with the code below?

**Code:**

```
private void ColorizeCellsbyValue() {

        DataGridViewCellStyle BoldRed = null;
        BoldRed = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        BoldRed.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
        BoldRed.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        DataGridViewCellStyle Red = null;
        Red = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        Red.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        DataGridViewCellStyle Black = null;
        Black = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        Black.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        string priority;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            priority = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            switch (priority)
            {
                //Change font 
                case "Urgent":
                    row.Cells[3].Style = BoldRed;
                    break;
                case "Haute":
                    row.Cells[3].Style = Red;
                    break;
                case "Normale":
                    row.Cells[3].Style = Black;
                    break;
                default:
                    row.Cells[3].Style = Black;
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
row.Cells[3].Style.BackColor = <Color>;
```

for `ForeColor` use

```
row.Cells[3].Style.ForeColor = <Color>;
```

This should work. Happy coding!

Comment: +1 but unfortunately the OP wants to _"change the font style"_ `:D`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a `DataGridViewCellStyle` to design your `Column` Properties. try to figure out my simple example

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (rows.Cells[3].RowIndex % 2 == 0)
            {
                rows.Cells[3].Style.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                rows.Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                rows.Cells[3].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
                rows.Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
        }
```

and my answer to your main problem is try to use `.EditedFormattedValue.ToString()`

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            priority = row.Cells[3].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
            switch (priority)
            {
                //Change font 
                case "Urgent":
                    row.Cells[3].Style = BoldRed;
                    break;
                case "Haute":
                    row.Cells[3].Style = Red;
                    break;
                case "Normale":
                    row.Cells[3].Style = Black;
                    break;
                default:
                    row.Cells[3].Style = Black;
                    break;
            }
        }
```